# Closest pairs of elements in two sorted arrays

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, closest, closest-points

We are looking for an efficient algorithm to solve the following problem:

> Given two increasingly sorted arrays.
> Find the closest corresponding elements in each array that difference is
> below a user given threshold. But only the closest of possible candidates
> (in the range of `array1[i] +/- threshold`) should be returned.
> The second closest could be matched to another element but
> matches to more than one element are not allowed. If two elements in
> `array1` have the same distance to `array2[j]` the first (leftmost) match
> should be reported.
>
> The arrays can contain duplicated values. There the first (leftmost) match
> should be reported (and all the others ignored/not matched).

Examples:

```
x: 1, 3, 5, 6, 8
y: 3, 4, 5, 7
threshold: 1
output: NA, 1, 3, 4, NA
(index of y that matches best to x)

x: 1, 1.5, 2, 2.1, 5, 6.1, 7.2
y: 4.6, 4.7, 4.8, 4.9, 5, 6, 7, 8
threshold: 3
output: NA, NA, NA, 1, 5, 6, 7
(index of y that matches best to x)

x: 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2
y: 1, 2
threshold: 0
output: 1, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA
(index of y that matches best to x, for duplicates choose to first one)

x: 1, 2
y: 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2
threshold: 0
output: 1, 4
(index of y that matches best to x, for duplicates choose to first one)
```

We use this to find the closest matching values between two *m/z*-values
(mass-to-charge ratios) while comparing mass spectra.

Currently we iterate through both arrays and lookahead the differences for the
next two elements and correct the previous element if a closer one was found.
But this fails for more than two duplicate elements in a row (second example):

Our current implementation (C code as part of an R package):
https://github.com/rformassspectrometry/MsCoreUtils/blob/master/src/closest.c#L73-L129

A commented version below:

```c
SEXP C_closest_dup_closest(SEXP x, SEXP table, SEXP tolerance, SEXP nomatch) {
    /* x is the first array of doubles */
    double *px = REAL(x);
    const unsigned int nx = LENGTH(x);

    /* table is the second array of doubles where x should be matched against */
    double *ptable = REAL(table);
    const unsigned int ntable = LENGTH(table);

    /* user given tolerance threshold */
    double *ptolerance = REAL(tolerance);

    /* integer array to store the results */
    SEXP out = PROTECT(allocVector(INTSXP, nx));
    int* pout = INTEGER(out);

    /* integer that should returned if no valid match or a closer one was found */
    const unsigned int inomatch = asInteger(nomatch);

    /* indices */
    unsigned int ix = 0, ixlastused = 1;
    unsigned int itbl = 0, itbllastused = 1;
    /* differences: current, difference to next element of x and table, respectively */
    double diff = R_PosInf, diffnxtx = R_PosInf, diffnxttbl = R_PosInf;

    while (ix < nx) {
        if (itbl < ntable) {
            /* difference for current pair */
            diff = fabs(px[ix] - ptable[itbl]);
            /* difference for next pairs */
            diffnxtx =
                ix + 1 < nx ? fabs(px[ix + 1] - ptable[itbl]) : R_PosInf;
            diffnxttbl =
                itbl + 1 < ntable ? fabs(px[ix] - ptable[itbl + 1]) : R_PosInf;

            if (diff <= ptolerance[ix]) {
                /* valid match, add + 1 to convert between R/C index */
                pout[ix] = itbl + 1;
                if (itbl == itbllastused &&
                        (diffnxtx < diffnxttbl || diff < diffnxttbl))
                    pout[ixlastused] = inomatch;
                ixlastused = ix;
                itbllastused = itbl;
            } else
                pout[ix] = inomatch;

            if (diffnxtx < diff || diffnxttbl < diff) {
                /* increment the index with the smaller distance */
                if (diffnxtx < diffnxttbl)
                    ++ix;
                else
                    ++itbl;
            } else {
                /* neither next x nor next table item offer a better match */
                ++ix;
                ++itbl;
            }
        } else
            pout[ix++] = inomatch;
    }

    /* R provided MACRO to free allocated memory */
    UNPROTECT(1);
    return out;
}
```

Could anybody give us a hint for a better algorithm?

Comment: Index [ + 1]? So the elements of `y` are only allowed to be used once? Sounds like an optimization problem that could use dynamic programming.

Comment: You could just do a binary search for each element of `x` in `y`. Test which of the elements adjacent to the binsearch result in `y` is closer to the element of `x`, then check whether it is within tolerance. If so, remove the element from `y` (to avoid matching it multiple times), store it as a match, continue with the next element of `x`. For optimization: Because `x` is sorted, you can adjust your starting position in `y` forwards for the binsearch occasionally (however note this pathological case: a later element of `x` can match an earlier element of `y`, if tolerance permits).

Comment: @Neil: indeed each element is just allowed to be used once.

Comment: @EOF: thanks for your suggestion. I guess I have to remove the duplicates before to ensure they are not matched.

Comment: It is not clear for me how to handle the case with duplicates in both arrays.

Comment: x: [2,3,4,5,6], y: [1,2,3,4,5], would the matches be 2-1, ... 6-5, or 2-2, 5-5, and not match 6? I think you need a metric to answer this, right?

Comment: @Damien: in case of duplicates always the first occurrence (leftmost) element should be matched, e.g. for `x: 1, 1, 2, 2; y 1, 1, 2, 2; threshold: 0;` the output should be `1, 3.

Comment: @Neil: `2-2, 3-3, 4-4, 5-5` and not matched: `1, 6`; We just use the absolute distance/difference as metric? Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: Then you have one less match. If you are okay with that, (_ie_, a cost of 0 for unmatched numbers), I think a greedy algorithm would be fine.

Comment: @Neil: I am fine when not all elements are matched. That's by intention. I am not a trained programmer, I have to read about greedy algorithms to answer whether it could be useful or not.

Comment: [2,3,4,5,6] and [6,7,8,9,10] should only match 6-6; it's greedy because each step takes the local optimum, _vs_ say you could double your matches with a slightly less optimum 5-6, 6-7. Greedy generally is quicker.

Comment: @Neil: "[2,3,4,5,6] and [6,7,8,9,10] should only match 6-6;" correct! Thanks, we don't care for more possible matches and run time is important because in spectra comparison/spectra library search etc. this function would be called thousand times.